# Edit button inside apps

Tags: buttons, ipad

I am working on an iPad app that will allow the user to edit content available on a shortlist (the left-hand side of the screen). The *Edit* option, however, will be available from the right hand-side of the screen (Blue button):

[image]

**Question:** Would it be more logical to have the edit option placed on the left (orange button) or right (blue button) side of the screen?

Comment: I have edited your question, but stil I am a little bit confused and would like to make sure I have not changed the meaning. Summary: The full list is presented on left, then items can be added to a shortlist presented in the right (blue) part of the screen. You want to ask if the Edit button should be on the left (orange [Edit] button) or right (blue [Edit] button). Am I right?

Comment: Yes Dom, the fundamental question is about best placement of an edit button when the content is presented on the left.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that there are some obvious drawbacks of how the layout is set up now, both regarding the edit CTA's and also the search field.

Let me start with the search field. The search field is in a top bar of the app, covering both the list container (left) and the item details container (right). This makes it quite confusing for a user to establish whether the search is mapped towards the list or the details area, or both even... I assume that the search is mapped towards the list, in that case it would be better to move it to the top of the list view to clearly map its functionality.

Now to the edit CTA. The mapping here is also quite confusing. The bar covers both the list and the details containers again, and it's also here hard to establish which container it's actually mapped towards. If this bar will only contain an Edit button, I would suggest moving the bar into the details container, clearly mapping what it is that the user can edit. This also solves the issue with having an edit button visible when no item in the list is selected.

Comment: "Now to the edit CTA. The mapping here is also quite confusing. The bar covers both the list and the details containers again, and it's also here hard to establish which container it's actually mapped towards." This is exactly what I think as well. There is no direct mapping to what the [Edit] button does (regardless placement). The bar, including the Edit button, should be just above the area containing items that can be edited by tapping it.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to have a split view like the default Email app used on iPad. Here the Edit is placed in a position that is similar to what you have just described. Is that right?

Comment: @Taritaro, what exactly do you want to edit?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo Exactly!

Comment: @Taritaro If the edit action is mapped towards the shortlist to the right then I would definitely argue that it should be placed inside the shortlist container, to clearly show what content the action will influence.

Comment: The EDIT action applies to the items in the vertical list. The draft was minimal because I wanted to focus the attention on the main elements of the design.

All I want to know is, keeping in mind that I do not want a split screen, and considering that the edit applies to the items on the right, would you keep the EDIT on the right (blue) or you would move it on the left (ORANGE).

I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @Taritaro - please edit this information into the question. You contradict yourself ("items in the vertical list" (which is on the LEFT) Vs. "the edit applies to the items on the right").